# How to determine if the slider is moved(or its value has changed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a slider in my code. Right now if I click on the slider an alert will pop up. But I want to pop up that alert only if the slider is moved or its value has been changed compared to previous movement. Is it possible.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {

         $("#slider-1").slider({
             range: true,
             min: 0,
             max: 500,
             values: [0, 0],
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 $("#priceA").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
             },
             stop: function () {
                 getValues();
             }
         });


     });

$("#slider-1").click(function(){
alert('Changed');
});      

});          
</script>
</head>
<p>
    <label for="priceA">Price rangeA:</label>
    <input type="text" id="priceA" style="border:0; color:#067ab4; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-1" class="myClass"></div><br><br>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery ui slider has a `change` event :
http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.value);
    }
});
```